# In the Proof of Kolmogorov's Strong Law of Large Numbers

Tags: probability-theory, martingales, law-of-large-numbers

I understand everything in this proof concerning the strong law of large numbers, except for the line highlighted in red.  I do not understand why $$\frac{X_1 + ...+X_n}{n}$$ is measurable with respect to the $\sigma$-field $\cap_{k=1}^\infty \sigma(X_{k+1}, X_{k+2}, ...)$.

My attempt at a justification:

Fix $k \in \mathbb{N}$.  $\frac{X_{k+1} + ...+X_{k+n}}{n}$ converges almost surely by the identical argument to the case where $k = 0$.  It suffices to show that $\text{lim}_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{X_{k+1} + ...+X_{k+n}}{n} = \text{lim}_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{X_1 + ...+X_n}{n}$, for in that case, since $\frac{X_{k+1} + ...+X_{k+n}}{n}$ is a $\sigma(X_{k+1}, X_{k+2}, ...)$ measurable random variable for every $k$, the result follows immediately.

Now fix $N > k$.  For all $n \ge N$, we have

$$\left|\frac{X_{k+1} + ...+X_{k+n}}{n} - \frac{X_1 + ...+X_n}{n} \right| =  \left|\frac{X_{n+1} + ...+X_{n+k}}{n} - \frac{X_1 + ...+X_k}{n} \right|$$

(all the middle terms $X_{k+1}, ..., X_{n}$ cancel out)

Now since $\frac{X_1 + ...+X_k}{k}$ is a convergent sequence, it is bounded so we can bound the second term inside the last absolute value by dividing and multiplying by $k$, but I don't know how to do the same thing for the first term based on the indices being different.  Please help!

For reference, this is taken from Jacod and Protter's "Probability Essentials" textbook.

[image]

Comment: Something is odd, $S_n/n$ given $\mathscr{F}_{-n}$ is just $S_n/n.$ Maybe they meant $\mathscr{F}_{-n} = \sigma(S_k; k > n)$? In that case, recall that $E(Y \mid \mathscr{G})$ is measurable relative to $\mathscr{G}.$

Comment: I think that's the point though.  They wish to say that $S_n/n$ converges almost surely to some limit.  If each martingale term is not necessarily measurable with respect to $\mathcal{F}_{-n}$, how can we say anything about the convergence of $S_n/n$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just realised the result is probably not that obvious.

Denote $\mathscr{G}_{n} = \sigma(X_k; k \geq n).$ Then,
$$X = \lim_{p \to \infty} \dfrac{S_{n + p}}{n + p} = \lim_{p \to \infty} \left( \dfrac{S_n}{n + p} + \dfrac{X_{n + 1} + \ldots + X_{n + p}}{n + p} \right) = \lim_{p \to \infty} \dfrac{X_{n + 1} + \ldots + X_{n + p}}{n + p}$$
is measurable relative to $\mathscr{G}_n,$ thus to $\bigcap\limits_{n \in \mathbf{N}} \mathscr{G}_n,$ which is the tail sigma field (by definition). Q.E.D.

Comment: Thank you for this.  I think it makes sense.  Just to clarify, we have that the $S_n/(n+p)$ vanishes because $S_n/n$ is bounded and $n/(n+p) \rightarrow 0$ as $p \rightarrow \infty$?

Comment: Fix $n,$ then $S_n$ is some real number ($\omega$-by-$\omega$), thus $S_n/(n+p)$ tends to zero in the real sense.

Comment: Thanks again.  This is much simpler than the avenue I was trying to go down.